# Dynamically change actionbar color while using a navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

I'm working on a project where I need to change the actionbar color within a single activity multiple times according to the content. This is done using

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

WITH this line, a portion of the actionbar turns transparent/grey (base theme is @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) as soon as the navigation drawer is opened.

WITHOUT it, the background stays solid as expected even when the navigation drawer is opened. However, this does not allow for diffrent colored pages.

I'm using the support actionbar from appcompat 7, but it can be reproduced with a Toolbar as well as on multiple android versions.

Any ideas WHY this happens? Have I just messed up or is this in fact a bug?

Any workarounds, apart from setting a fixed color for the actionbar?

[image: Bug]

*Note the right area of the actionbar that has become grey/transparent after opening the navigation drawer*

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Kind of...
Please post other solutions if you can improve on this, as it is not the cleanest solution.

Changing the above mentioned

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

to

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(((ColorDrawable) colorDrawable).getColor()));
```

solved the problem for me. This really should not have to be done though.